# как создать контейнер со списком функций?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

void printStr(const std::string & str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
void printInt(const int & i)
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, void(*)(...)> map;
    map["prints"] = &printStr;
    map["printi"] = &printInt;
    map["prints"]("12345");
    map["printi"](1234);
    return 0;
}
```

этот код не работает, а функции с std::cout для примера. я бы хотел составить список указателей на статические функции, чтобы во время исполнения программы можно было вызвать любую из них с любым количеством параметров из командной строки и таким образом менять значения полей экземпляра какого-то своего класса. как правильно это сделать? и есть ли что-то подобное уже готовое в стандартных или бесплатных библиотеках?

Comment: Допустим, у вас получилось. Все равно вы должны вызывать только руками: как вы *во время работы программы* правильно передадите аргументы в ситуации типа `string name; cin>>name; map[name](???);` — что вы напишете вместо `???`? Всегда удивляет такое вот "гетерогенное" проектирование, плюющее на систему типов...

Comment: Функции нужно привести к единому виду, например с одним параметром `const std::string &` (или какой-нибудь JSON).

Это можно автоматизировать шаблонами, или, для простоты, написать руками.

Comment: @Harry я бы хотел вводить в консоль строчку вида: `func_name 1 "2"` (разделительный символ - пробел). распознавать, что имя функции "func_name", 1 -- это int, а в кавычках -- это std:string. это будет значить, что нужно вызвать `map["func_name"](1,"2")`. для начала так. в будущем "список команд" будет считываться из текстового файла и исполняться.  это будет очередной "движок" на opengl, когда и если смогу

Comment: другой пример: ввод в консоль `func2` будет значить, что нужно вызывать `map["func2"]()`, т.е. без параметров.

Comment: А как планируете вызывать тот же `map["func_name"](1,"2")`? Как в самом исходном тексте укажете, что тут именно два параметра, а не один? Через какой-то `switch` от количества параметров? Словом, напишите кусочек кода и посмотрите, как оно будет получаться... Я бы, как вариант, делал через классы, а класс функции уже сам со строкой аргументов должен был бы разбираться.

Comment: @harry я в соседней теме подсмотрел такое решение: ` std::vector<void(*)()> vec;
    vec.push_back([]{printInt(10);});
    vec.back()();`. какая-то магия, недоступная моему разумению, но она решает вопрос, как из файла "набор команд" перенести в "очередь" и потом из этой очереди исполнить. и, скорее всего, можно нечто подобное сделать с std::map

Comment: @user, так ведь Harry вам абсолютно то же самое и написал в ответе. Функция любого типа преобразовывается в void* и кладётся в контейнер.

Comment: @maestro
 благодарю, словами суть стала немного понятее. в ответе ниже я совершенно не понял, `typedef void (*iFunc)(const int &);`.  `typedef тип псевдоним` же аналогично `#define тип псевдоним`, зачем для void такой псевдоним?

Comment: Это преобразование *назад* в функцию, чтоб вызвать можно было — с нужными аргументами... Тот фрагмент, что вы привели — использование лямбда-функции, но для чего серьезнее, функций разного типа, как у вас — без шаманского бубна и плясок не заработает...

Comment: @user, `define` - это не псевдоним, а текстовая замена. То есть до того, как приступить к компиляции, компилятор сначала выполняет текстовые подстановки, заданные директивами препроцессора: `define`, `include` и т.д. А typedef - это создание нового типа, который равен какому-то другому известному (обычно сложному).

Comment: @maestro `map.emplace("prints", [](){printStr(s);}); map["prints"]();` -- такой код работает, но когда я пытаюсь передать аргументы позже, то уже не работает. `map.emplace("prints", [](std::string s){printStr(s);}); map["prints"]("123");`, где `std::map<std::string, void(*)()> map;`. это невозможно или я неправильно пытаюсь использовать лямбда-функции?

Comment: @user, вы правильно используете лямбда-функции. У вас не работает потому, что отсутствует *обратное преобразование* из типа `void(*)()` в тип настоящей функции (см. ответ Harry). Сущность, имеющую тип `void(*)()`, вызвать невозможно.

Comment: Ой, поправочка... Можно вызвать, но только без аргументов. А вы передаёте один аргумент. Поэтому и выдаёт вам ошибку.

Comment: @maestro тогда, если я всё правильно понял, нет никакого смысла использовать std::map. если всё равно придётся через if-else выбирать подходящую функцию для преобразования, тогда проще через этот же if-else просто вызвать функцию. а вот добавлять в std::vector с заранее установленными параметрами, чтобы вызвать позже -- это полезно.

Comment: Что за вектор с заранее установленными параметрами? Что вы добавляете указатель на функцию в `std::map`, что в `std::vector`, вы теряете информацию о типах. Это приводит к практической бесполезности всей идеи помещения функций разных типов в контейнеры.

Comment: @maestro я имел ввиду такой код, при добавлении в std::vector сразу передаются значения: `std::vector<void(*)()> vec;
    vec.push_back([]{std::cout << 10 << std::endl;});
    vec.push_back([]{std::cout << "123" << std::endl;});
    for (auto element : vec)
    {
        element();
    }`  -- это работает. добавляю 2 "задачи" в std::vector, затем их вызываю. осталось разобраться, как без повторного заполнения выполнить те же задачи, но с другими значениями того же типа. преобразование типов будет до добавления в "список"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот вариант. Только с вас — как обязательное условие :) —  демонстрация того, как именно вы будете это все использовать...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

typedef void (*sFunc)(const std::string &);
typedef void (*iFunc)(const int &);

void printStr(const std::string & str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
void printInt(const int & i)
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, void*> map;
    map["prints"] = (void*)printStr;
    map["printi"] = (void*)printInt;
    (sFunc(map["prints"]))("12345");
    (iFunc(map["printi"]))(1234);
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

Набросал простенькое решение, как бы, возможно, делал я (хотя уже вижу ряд улучшений).

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Func
{
public:
    virtual string name() const = 0;
    virtual void doit(const string&) = 0;
};

vector<Func*> funcs;

class Sum: public Func
{
public:
    string name() const override { return "sum"; }
    void doit(const string& s)
    {
        istringstream is(s);
        int a, b;
        string n;
        is >> n >> a >> b;
        cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << (a+b) << endl;
    }
};

class Str: public Func
{
public:
    string name() const override { return "str"; }
    void doit(const string& s)
    {
        cout << "string = " << s << endl;
    }
};

void handle(const string& s)
{
    for(const auto& f: funcs)
        if (s.starts_with(f->name()))
        {
            f->doit(s);
            break;
        }
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    funcs.push_back(new Sum);
    funcs.push_back(new Str);


    handle("sum 5 8");
    handle("str Hello world");

}
```

Есть абстрактный класс, производные — ваши функции, выполняющие сами разбор строки (им виднее!) и нужные вызовы. Объект вносится в какой-то контейнер, при разборе строки выбирается подходящий и работает. Ошибки не обрабатываю, чисто набросок, как и высосанная из пальца функциональность...

Все, что надо для расширения функциональности (новая функция) — новый класс, 2 функции, объект класса в контейнер. Все.

Comment: Дописал немного, чтоб пояснить свое предложение. Как по мне, проще, понятнее, гораздо лучше расширяется...

Comment: `map["prints"] = printStr;` — так нельзя. [Нужен `reinterpret_cast`](https://godbolt.org/z/bzfxcW36h).

Comment: @wololo Вообще-то да, но VC++ это пропустил :)