# Вызов функции из аргумента(C++)

Tags: c++, linux, map

Пишу консольную программу "Органаизер" на С++ и дошел до момента проверки комманд. Пытаюсь сделать это через словарь(map)
`map <string, void*> AvailableCommands;`

То есть вводится команда, проверяется наличие ключа и после этого мне нужно запустить функцию, которая передаётся в качестве значения словаря. Как это сделать? Можно ли так делать или же лучше это сделать по другому?

Comment: Вы не это ищете? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1523119/195342

Answer (score 0):

**Ну смотри**

делаешь if, else с проверкой строки на название команды, после уже руками вызываешь нужные функции
надеюсь помог

P.S я новичек так что если я что то не так написал, напишите мне в ответ